# How to import ErrorObservable or _throw in rxjs6? throw in rxjs

Tags: angular, migration, rxjs, throw, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I am migrating to rxjs `6.0.0-ucandoit-rc.6`. In version `5.5.2` I was using `ErrorObservable` to create errorous observable.

I was using the way recommended here: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md

> Because throw is a key word you could use _throw after import { _throw } from 'rxjs/observable/throw'.

However this is not recommended way to import in rxjs6 anymore.

What is correct way how to import `_throw` or `ErrorObservable`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In RxJS version 6, `_throw` has been renamed to [`throwError`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.0.0-ucandoit-rc.6/src/index.ts#L62) and should be imported like this:

```
import { throwError } from "rxjs";
```

Alternatively, you can install `rxjs-compat` alongside `rxjs` version 6 to continue to use the old, version 5 exports:

```
import { _throw } from "rxjs/observable/throw";
```

For more information, see the [migration guide](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md).

Comment: `import { _throw } from "rxjs/observable/throw";` does not appear to work even with rxjs-compat imported.

Comment: It works just fine for me with `rsjx` and `rxjs-compat` version `6.0.0` installed. No doubt you have some sort of error that's effected. It should give you a hint as to what could be wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I was playing with throw on [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-y9xtfu?file=index.ts), and upgraded to latest 6.0.0 (also prompted for rxjs-compat), but it shows the dreaded red squiggly on 'rxjs/observable/throw'. Seems to be an artefact of StackBlitz, because if I export it and npm install, it looks ok.

Comment: I see what you mean. And the error isn't exactly actionable. Frustrating.

Comment: I was wondering if there's something needs tweaking in `rxjs-compat`. At least, this is a welcome step considering the churn in rxjs syntax over the last several releases.

Comment: Can get passed it with `import { Observable } from "rxjs"; const _throw = Observable.throw;`, but then it is not happy with the invocation (despite having intellisense that contradicts the error).

Comment: Even if there is something weird with `rxjs-compat`, if it cannot be reproduced outside of StackBlitz, I doubt the issue would get much traction. It's certainly not something I'd be keen to investigate.

Comment: It's just a shame because StackBlitz is one of the few online runners that gets a test Angular app up quickly, and there is an ever tightening dependency between Angular and rxjs.

Comment: Actually, it's not a show-stopper as `_throw('my error')` still works.

Comment: I think the better way to use this to import { throwError } from 'rxjs/internal/observable/throwError'

Comment: @Keyvan Absolutely not. You should not import from any of the `internal` locations. They are not intended to be consumed publicly and could be changed at any time.